# Spring Security Method Annotations -- Do they require DispatchServlet

Tags: security, spring

I'm learning Spring Security. (I used to program in Java extensively years ago). I couldn't get Spring *method* security to work despite reading the documentaion multiple times and reading multiple websites (including StackOverflow).

However, I'm now wondering if one must implement "DispatchServlet" in order for the Spring Method Security annotations to take effect?  (When I read through the Spring Security documentation, they do NOT even reference the DispatchServlet (http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html); however, the sample security examples do. 
That said, I do know that DispatchServlet is not needed if one wants to use the Spring Security Authentication module -- it seems that that in that case, just using the "DelegatingProxy" filter is sufficient.)

Comment: No, `DispatchServlet` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried pretty much everything. Is there a way I could actually pay for some help on this via a GoToMeeting etc.? (I'm a small time entrepreneur, so I'm totally cash strapped, but I now truly need help.) My email is gsaxena888@gmail.com

Comment: I had a conversation with Dave Newton (above). He helped tremendously. Long story short: Since I'm using GWT for my solution, using only the FilterChain was not sufficient to get the "@Service" annotated classes to be part of the Spring Containers. Instead, with Dave pointing me in the right direction, I used "Spring4GWT": [link] (http://code.google.com/p/spring4gwt/). It worked, though the documentation in the examples was not 100% correct (though it was easy to fix).

Comment: You should add that as an answer and accept it; you did all the leg work, and I bet that other people would like to see how it all ended up being set up.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need DispatcherServlet  unless you need to need to dispatch requests to  a Spring based controller . i.e, when you use Spring MVC . Read [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) for more info.

If you are using Spring security , You need to have the configuration file properly written and this could be loaded via the ContextLoaderListener in the web.xml or through ClassPathXmlApplicationContext-

A sample of the web.xml configuration is below.Also you will need the Spring-Security dependencies.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring/spring-security.xml,
    </param-value>       
</context-param>
```